# Adding a new TFS server resulting in error: "Server already exists in the list below"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

While trying to add a TFS server to Visual Studio 2017, I encountered an issue where it claims that the server already exists in the list. However, it does not.

The only thing that I can think of that could cause it to think that the server is in the list, is that the two servers used to be one. This was not an issue with Visual Studio 2015.

The TFS servers are both 2015 update 3.

Comment: If the server was split into two servers, it's very important that the Server ID was changed when setting up the second server. Very weird behavior can happen otherwise. Same goes for collection IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try with directly **using IP address** instead of server name when you are adding Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio. Something like:

```
http://192.168.0.1:8080/tfs
```

You can also find your Team Foundation Server 2015 **GUID** Info in the below location:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config
```

There should be a value like

[image]

Then you could compare the GUIDs of the two servers, change one of them, and re-register the db. For more details about it, take a look at this blog post: [How to find Team Foundation Server(TFS) GUID Info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2014/04/07/how-to-find-team-foundation-servertfs-2012-guid-info/)

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT How do you re-register the DB once you've changed the GUID?

Comment: @Eritey Why you want to re-register the DB. Have you finished the TFS upgrade or something else? Could you describe more clearly about your situation?

Comment: I recommend removing the suggestion about using the IP address since that doesn't resolve the issue here, which is that a cloned environment will have the same applicationId and needs to have a new one applied.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

1. Close VS 2017.
2. Open explorer and go to %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_92d7e574. Delete all files.
3. Go to %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_92d7e574. Delete all files.
4. Start VS 2017 and enter the TFS server address.

Answer (score 0):

We just did the upgrade and found out that VS 2017 expects (at least for now) that there should only be 1 TFS server present, so you would need to remove the old one, then add the new one.  It's probably some confusion with the TFS Workspace. The "Connect" box may still give the error, but after removing the old, adding the new, and pressing the "Connect" button, it worked just fine for me.

Comment: This doesn't address OP's situation, where they _want_ to have two separate TFS instances.