# Visual studio tfs multiple server add issue

Tags: tfs

I have TFS server connected to visual studio. And
I have restore it to another tfs server differnet name. Now i need add new server to visual studio. When i try to add it getting server with same id already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the TFS or Azure DevOps Server's ID or GUID of the new instance. You can do that by using the [TFSConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2019#changeserverid) command line.

```
TfsConfig changeServerID /sqlInstance:<serverName> /databaseName:<configurationDatabaseName>
[/projectCollectionsOnly] [/configDBOnly] [/collectionName]
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure your detail process of restoring operation. However according to your description, guess you may have two  same server ID(applicationID)

You could find your old Team Foundation Server  **GUID** Info in below location:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 1x.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config
```

There should be a value like

[image]

Then you could compare the GUID of two servers old and new TFS server, change one of them and re-register db. You may need to restart sever, tfs service.

More details about it, please take a look at this blog: [How to find Team Foundation Server(TFS) GUID Info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2014/04/07/how-to-find-team-foundation-servertfs-2012-guid-info/)

As how to change server ID, just as Niel mentioned, you could use TFSConfig command:

```
TFSConfig ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:server_db /DatabaseName:TFS_Configuration
```

**Note:** After you use the changeServerID command, you must direct clients to create a connection to the changed server before it can be used.

Comment: This repeats the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791110/adding-a-new-tfs-server-resulting-in-error-server-already-exists-in-the-list-b/42799908#42799908--instead of reposting solutions, please vote to close as duplicates, instead.